# Why is using a dict so much faster to exclude one list from another?

Tags: python

I was surprised how different the speed was in two approaches to exclude one list of tuples for another. So I was wondering why.

I have a list for 1,500 tuples in the form of (int, float), sorted by the `float` value. (ADDED NOTE: each int value in the tuple list is distinct.) I wanted to figure out the fastest way to exclude a sublist. So first I created a sublist to exclude:

```
exclude_list = [v for i,v in enumerate(tuple_list) if (i % 3) == 0]
```

Then I timed two different approaches to removing `exclude_list` from `tuple_list` (but these aren't the two approaches I finally settled on):

```
remainder_list = [v for v in tuple_list if v not in exclude_list]
```

and,

```
remainder_set = set(tuple_list) - set(exclude_list)
remainder_list = sorted(remainder_set, key=itemgetter(1)) #edited to chance key to 1 from 0
```

The difference in time was huge: 14.7235 seconds (500 times) for the first approach and 0.3426  (500 times) for the second approach. I understand why these two approaches have such a different amount of time because the first requires searching through a sub_list for each item in the main list. So then, I came up with a better way to search/exclude:

```
exclude_dict = dict(exclude_list)
remainder_list = [v for v in tuple_list if v[0] not in exclude_dict]
```

I didn't think this version of excluding list items would be much faster than the first. Not only was it faster than the first approach, but it was faster than the second! It times in at 0.11177 (500 times). Why is this faster than my set-difference/resort approach?

Comment: Maybe because it stays sorted? Also, when you check for the element being in the dictionary, that takes constant time (dictionary is hashed) and does not perform a linear search.

Comment: As a side note, I don't think you actually want to use a `dict` here.  If you have two tuples which have the same first integer in your tuple_list, then you could get incorrect results (which is why I used a `set` in my answer instead) -- e.g. things could be incorrectly excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in` operator for a list is O(N) to compute.  It just does a linear search.  To do better, you could change `exclude_list` to `exclude_set`:

```
exclude_set = {v for i,v in enumerate(tuple_list) if (i % 3) == 0}
```

Or, if you already have `exclude_list`:

```
exclude_set = set(exclude_list)
```

and then calculate your `remainder_list` as before:

```
remainder_list = [v for v in tuple_list if v not in exclude_set]
```

This is **WAY** better because `in` for a set is a very impressive O(1) (on average).  And here, you don't need to re-sort the `remainder_list` either, so that removes an O(MlogM) step (where `M == len(remainder_list`))

---

Of course, with this trivial example, we could construct the whole thing with 1 list-comp:

```
remainder_list = [v for i,v in enumerate(tuple_list) if (i % 3) != 0]
```

Comment: The bit about the `exclude_list` creation was just to show how I made the `exclude_list`. What I was timing didn't involve the creating of this list, but rather the way I excluded the `exclude_list` from the 'tuple_list`. I used a set-difference/resort approach and a dict/look-up approach, and was surprised the second was faster.

Comment: @Cole -- I understand that.  I'm just saying that using a proper data structure to hold the information that you want to exclude will speed things up and that the list version is slow because to check if an element is to be excluded is an O(N) operation.

Comment: I love your answer. It clocks in at 0.09534. Unfortunately, the function I am building uses two lists as inputs. So any change to the type of one of the lists has to happen within the function. When I perform `dict(exclude_list)` before the function loads, it times in at .10133, so your approach is faster on that basis. Is there something better to do within the function than using `dict(exclude_list)`?

Comment: @Cole -- There's no really good way to tell without seeing the function.  Why do the inputs *have* to be lists?  Due to the wonderfulness of duck-typing, depending on what you're doing with the lists, etc, you should be able to pass in a list, a set or anything else that supports `__contains__`.

Comment: It should be trivial for to make it so the input to the function can be a set. Also, since the `int` values in the `(int, float)` tuples are distinct, I can have the input as the set of `int` values. That adds a little more speed to using a set of the list tuples.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check the [time complexity of list and set operations](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

```
remainder_list = [v for v in tuple_list if v not in exclude_list]
```

`in` operation here is O(N), it looks through all the elements in the tuple_list to see if the element exists in exclude_list or not. So its complexity is `O(len(tuple_list) * len(exclude_list))`

The difference `-` operation on a set has O(n) complexity since a set uses a hashtable as it's underlying data structure and has O(1) membership checking. Thus the line:

```
remainder_set = set(tuple_list) - set(exclude_list).
```

has `O(len(tuple_list))` complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithms are not equivalent. Your elements are couples. With the first two methods you exclude elements by matching couples. With the third method (with dict) you exclude elements comparing only the first element of your couples.

If the couples have few different first elements the dict method is then much faster but the result could be different.

Comment: The first item in each tuple is distinct. I should have said so explicitly.

Comment: but anyway your first and second method compare both items. The third method compares only the first one.